# Insert,delete operations always successful but returns -1,0 values sometimes

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

```
if (!listedeBulundu) {
        Log.e("tag","Yerleştirme bloğuna girildi")
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val dbInsertDeferred = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                viewModel.roomRepository.VeritabaninaYerlestir(scp)
            }

            val dbInsert = dbInsertDeferred.await()
            Log.e("tag",dbInsert.toString())
            
            if (dbInsert != -1L) {
                viewModel.roomRepository.VeritabanindanGetir()
                yazdir()
                Log.e("tag", "Yerleştirme işlemi başarılı")
            } else {
                Log.e("tag", "Yerleştirme işlemi başarısız")
            }
        }
        favoriSimgesi = true
    }
```

Inserting to room database is always successful.But returns -1 sometimes.Deleting from room database also is always successful but returns 0 sometimes.How do i solve this ?

Comment: Unrelated, but please don't use `CoroutineScope(...).launch { ... }` like this. It is explicitly deemed wrong by [the `GlobalScope` documentation}(https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/). Instead, store that scope somewhere and cancel it appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return the result of the coroutine operation from outside the coroutine. The coroutine itself is asynchronous from the code immediately following it. The only way you could return the result from this function is to make the function a suspend function that calls the code directly instead of launching a coroutine. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o) for more explanation. Basically, your line of code `favoriSimgesi = true` executes before or in parallel with the code inside your coroutine. The function that launches this coroutine likely returns before the coroutine is finished.

It is also incorrect to be using `async { }` inside your coroutine only to await it right away. That's redundant and unnecessary complexity. `async` is for doing parallel work, which you are not doing since you immediately `await` the result before doing anything else.

And as mentioned in the comment on your question, you should not use `CoroutineScope().launch`. This is like using `GlobalScope`, and it will lead to memory and resource leaks. In this case I am inferring your code is in an Activity or Fragment, so you should be using `lifecycleScope` or `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response its very instructive to me.Neither both ,my code is in a class.My teacher said you should always use CoroutineScope().launch whenever you want to use database.And I didnt understand how do we call a suspend function without coroutine ? Its illegal init{
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO){
gettheResponse()
}
}

suspend fun gettheResponse()
{
viewModel.roomRepository.VeritabaninaYerlestir(scp)
}

Comment: `CoroutineScope().launch` is essentially an alias of `GlobalScope.launch`, but it's explicitly called out in the [documentation of `GlobalScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) not to do this.  [Global coroutine scopes should usually be avoided](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) but are appropriate for actions that should not be cancelled under any lifecycle event, so they might make sense for database writes...

Comment: ...but then you could use GlobalScope instead of creating a separate one-time-use scope. But an injected CoroutineScope would be preferable to GlobalScope so it can be unit tested more effectively. In your case however, your coroutine isn't only writing to a database. It is also working with UI, so you are creating memory/resource leaks.

Comment: Correct, you cannot call a suspend function without a coroutine. You should launch a coroutine to call it. Somewhere in your UI layer, you will launch a coroutine and does a sequence of actions *inside* that coroutine. So this function can suspend and return a value, and then you can use that value *inside* the coroutine you called it from.